# Setting file paths in eclipse projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

In my JSP and servlets web app, I have this line in a TLD or XML file in eclipse - `<%@ taglib prefix="mine" uri="DiceFunctions"%>` It gives me the error - `Eclispe can not find 
the tag library descriptor for "../DiceFunctions"`

I know this has something to do with the path `uri="DiceFunctions"` in the above code.
How do I resolve this error ?

**My project sturcture -**

[image]

Comment: Strange. This error went away after restarting eclipse twice. This silly thing has happened in a previous question. With errors like this, how does one even know if they are at fault ?

Comment: Did you trigger a build without realizing it? That's when it validates JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you create a taglib named 'mine' ?
you should read some doc about jsp taglib ;
The uri="DiceFunctions" is your taglib`s path